# MVC5 VB.Net - Single dbContext and Migrations

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

This is somewhat to do with best practice, but also some practical questions.

I'm new to MVC, and .Net in general, having been a PHP developer previously. I'm loving it on the whole, and Entity Framework / Code First is a bit special.

So I've done a bit of work on my first project, and my first issue is that there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation for VB - I can't use C# because the other developers here are all VB guys. I can get around that on the whole but does anyone know of a good resource, book or online, for MVC5 & VB?

Now for my problem. My project is going to contain a lot of data. I've no problem with creating the models and using migrations to get the tables up and running, and I can query them with complex joins, get my views to work, dynamic forms and whatnot.

Currently I have two data connections, one for the Identity stuff, and one for everything else (as in the examples on the MVC site).

This week the brief has changed and I now need to include more user data, and link my users to other tables in my other connection.

For example, I need to add a clientCompany table, with a corresponding field in my Users Table. A given clientCompany will have salesRegions, which each have postCodes, etc. etc.

So to join my Identity User table to my others, and set up foreign keys, would they need to occupy the same connection, and dbContext?

I seem to be able to have migrations set up for just one of my dbContexts at a time, so that makes me think I need to have everything in one dbContext. I've seen discussions about Inheriting the IdentityDbContext in my own dbContext class, but I can't get it to work - only the Identity tables, and tables linked to them by FKs are creating / updating.

Here's my IdentityModels.vb

```
Public Class ApplicationUser
    Inherits IdentityUser
    Property emailAddress() As String
    Overridable Property clientCompany() As ClientCompany
End Class

Public Class ApplicationDbContext
    Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser)

    Public Class IdentityDbContext
        Public Property IdentityDbContext() As ApplicationDbContext
    End Class
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("ExportEntities")
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's my own dbContext class, ExportEntities.vb

```
Namespace models

Public Class ExportEntities

    'Inherits DbContext
    Inherits IdentityDbContext

    'Metadata Heirarchy
    Public Property Products() As DbSet(Of Product)
    Public Property ProductVersions() As DbSet(Of ProductVersion)
    Public Property dbSplits() As DbSet(Of dbSplit)
    Public Property Sections() As DbSet(Of Section)
    Public Property FieldGroups() As DbSet(Of FieldGroup) 'Not all fields are organised into groups
    Public Property FieldNames() As DbSet(Of FieldName)

etc...
```

And finally my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="ExportEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\Export.mdf&quot;;Initial Catalog=&quot;Export&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end, I'll post the basics here in case it can benefit anyone else.

In my own data class, I inherit DbContext and add DbSets for the Identity tables, and added the onModelCreating sub at the end:

```
Public Class MyDataClass

    Inherits DbContext

    'Identity Tables
    Public Property AspNetRoles As DbSet(Of IdentityRole)
    Public Property AspNetUserClaims As DbSet(Of IdentityUserClaim)
    Public Property AspNetUserLogins As DbSet(Of IdentityUserLogin)
    Public Property AspNetUserRoles As DbSet(Of IdentityUserRole)
    Public Property AspNetUsers As DbSet(Of ApplicationUser)

    'All of my other data...

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of IdentityRole)().HasKey(Of String)(Function(r) r.Id).[Property](Function(p) p.Name).IsRequired()
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of IdentityUserRole)().HasKey(Function(r) New With { _
            r.RoleId, _
            r.UserId _
        })
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of IdentityUserLogin)().HasKey(Function(u) New With { _
            u.UserId, _
            u.LoginProvider, _
            u.ProviderKey _
        })
    End Sub
End Class
```

In IdentityModels.vb, I removed the section defining the base as DefaultConnection, leaving this:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports exportApp.exportApp.models
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

' You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
Public Class ApplicationUser
    Inherits IdentityUser
    Property emailAddress() As String
    Overridable Property clientCompany() As ClientCompany
End Class
```

I created a class ApplicationDbContext. Note `MyDataClass` in the `New()` Sub:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports System.Data.Entity

Namespace exportApp.models
Public Class ApplicationDbContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Overridable Property Users() As IDbSet(Of ApplicationUser)
        Get
            Return m_Users
        End Get
        Set(value As IDbSet(Of ApplicationUser))
            m_Users = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Users As IDbSet(Of ApplicationUser)

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("MyDataClass")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        If modelBuilder Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder")
        End If
         modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType(models.Configurations.ApplicationUserConfiguration).Assembly)
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Finally, I added a 'Configurations' folder to the 'Models' folder, and added the following five classes. This was the part I had been missing before.

ApplicationUserConfiguration.vb:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web

Namespace myApp.models.Configurations
Public Class ApplicationUserConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of ApplicationUser)
    Public Sub New()
        [Property](Function(u) u.UserName).IsRequired()
        HasMany(Of IdentityUserRole)(Function(u) u.Roles)
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

IdentityRoleConfiguration.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web

Namespace myApp.models.Configurations
Public Class IdentityRoleConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of IdentityRole)
    Public Sub New()
        [Property](Function(r) r.Name).IsRequired()
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

IdentityUserClaimConfiguration.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web

Namespace myApp.models.Configurations
Public Class IdentityUserClaimConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of IdentityUserClaim)
    Public Sub New()
        HasRequired(Function(u) u.User)
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

IdentityUserLoginConfiguration.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data.Entity

Namespace myApp.models.Configurations
Public Class IdentityUserLoginConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of IdentityUserLogin)
    Public Sub New()
        HasKey(Function(l) New With { _
            l.UserId, _
            l.LoginProvider, _
            l.ProviderKey _
        })
        HasRequired(Of IdentityUser)(Function(u) u.User)
    End Sub

End Class
End Namespace
```

IdentityUserRoleConfiguration.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web

Namespace CustomUser.Models.Configurations
Public Class IdentityUserRoleConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of IdentityUserRole)
    Public Sub New()
        HasKey(Function(r) New With { _
            r.UserId, _
            r.RoleId _
        })
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

I think that's about it. Add a migration, update the database, and I was away.

Hope this helps others out there, and if anyone can contribute, or suggest a better way round, I'd love to talk!